# ol.control.MousePosition EPSG:4326 over 180/-180 longitude (OL4)

Tags: openlayers

i will use a OpenLayers example in EPSG:4326, but the value of longitude is not wrapping on 180/-180 longitude.

How can i fix it?
My first problem is, i can't pick the values of latitude and longitude in a value for a if calculation.

```
if (lon > 180) {  
lon = (((lon / 180) - Math.floor(lon / 180)) * 180);
}
if (lon < -180) {
lon = (((((lon * -1) / 180) - Math.floor((lon * -1) / 180)) * (180 * -1) + 180));
}
```

How do I extract the coordinates into a variable?
Or is there another solution?

The OpenLayers Example:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mouse-position.html

The OL example in a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eqjjp4u8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your `ol.control.MousePosition`:

```
var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
    coordinateFormat: function(coordinate) {
        lon = coordinate[0];
        lat = coordinate[1];
        lon = lon % 360;
        if (lon > 180) {  
          lon = lon - 360;
        } else if (lon < -180) {
          lon = 360 + lon;
        }
        modifiedCoordinate = [lon, lat]
        return ol.coordinate.format(modifiedCoordinate, "{x}, {y}", 4);
    },
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    className: 'custom-mouse-position',
    target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
    undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
});
```

Check out your modified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqjjp4u8/7/).

**Update**: Now using `modifiedCoordinate` to limit the number of digits!

Comment: Okay, "coordinate[]" is the key to solution. And with modulo it's perfectly! **Many thanks!**

Comment: Please edit it with "return ol.coordinate.format(coordinate, '{y}, {x}', 4);". The digit-shortener "4" don't work in you JSFiddle.

Comment: oooops. Use ist with '{y}, {x}' destroy the wrapping function. OK, i have no solution on this time for the digit-shortener.

Comment: return ol.coordinate.format(coordinate, lat.toFixed(4) + ', ' + lon.toFixed(4));

Comment: Lars!!! The if/else calculation is not correct.

Comment: Sorry about that. I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Lars! yet the wrapping in east from 180 to -180 is still broken.

Comment: Copied the wrong JsFiddle link. Now it is correct!

Comment: Perfectly! i have deleted my answer.